# Dependencies not installed in conda environment within a Docker container

Tags: python, bash, docker, conda, miniconda

This exact Dockerfile was working 2 weeks ago and I can't figure out why it's not workingnow.  Nothing has changed in the script.

Here's the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jolespin/veba/blob/main/install/docker/Dockerfile)

```
# v2023.6.6
# =================================
# Miniconda3
# =================================

FROM continuumio/miniconda3

ARG ENV_NAME

SHELL ["/bin/bash","-l", "-c"]

WORKDIR /root/

# Data
RUN mkdir -p /volumes/input
RUN mkdir -p /volumes/output
RUN mkdir -p /volumes/database


# Retrieve VEBA repository
RUN mkdir -p veba/
COPY ./install/ veba/install/
COPY ./src/ veba/src/
COPY ./VERSION veba/VERSION
COPY ./LICENSE veba/LICENSE

# Install Miniconda
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda init bash && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda config --add channels jolespin && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda config --add channels bioconda && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda config --add channels conda-forge && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda update conda -y && \
    # /opt/conda/bin/conda install -c conda-forge mamba -y && \ # Mamba adds about 450 MB to image
    # /opt/conda/bin/mamba init bash && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda clean -afy

# =================================

# Add conda bin to path
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

# Create environment
RUN conda env create -n ${ENV_NAME} -f veba/install/environments/${ENV_NAME}.yml
# RUN mamba env create -n ${ENV_NAME} -f veba/install/environments/${ENV_NAME}.yml

# Add environment scripts to environment bin
RUN /bin/bash veba/install/update_environment_scripts.sh veba/

# # Add contents to path
# ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/${ENV_NAME}/bin:$PATH

# Set up environment
RUN echo "conda activate ${ENV_NAME}" >> ~/.bashrc

# Set entrypoint to bash
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-l", "-c"]
```

Here's my [environment.yml](https://github.com/jolespin/veba/blob/main/install/environments/VEBA-preprocess_env.yml) file

Last time I built this image, my dockerfile created exactly as expected. Now it's not even installing pandas.  I tried launching a docker container and manually installing.  No errors were thrown but it didn't install any of the dependencies.

This is from within the Docker container in an interactive session:

```
(base) root@c3be34361e98:~# conda env create -n test_env -f veba/install/environments/VEBA-preprocess_env.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.5.0
  latest version: 23.7.2

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=23.7.2



Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate test_env
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

(base) root@c3be34361e98:~# conda activate test_env
(test_env) root@c3be34361e98:~# conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     /opt/conda
test_env              *  /opt/conda/envs/test_env

(test_env) root@c3be34361e98:~# conda list
# packages in environment at /opt/conda/envs/test_env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.7.22            hbcca054_0    conda-forge
dependencies              7.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.40                 h41732ed_0    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.5.0                hcb278e6_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 13.1.0               he5830b7_0    conda-forge
libgomp                   13.1.0               he5830b7_0    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.0                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.42.0               h2797004_0    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.1                hd590300_1    conda-forge
pip                       23.2.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.11.4          hab00c5b_0_cpython    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
setuptools                68.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h27826a3_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023c                h71feb2d_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.41.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
```

My question:

**Why is my conda not installing the dependencies within the Docker container?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment part works fine with the latest Micromamba image:

```bash
FROM mambaorg/micromamba:1.4.9
COPY --chown=$MAMBA_USER:$MAMBA_USER VEBA-preprocess_env.yml /tmp/env.yml

RUN micromamba install -yn base -f /tmp/env.yml && \
    micromamba clean -qafy
```

Consider starting over from this, since it implements some better practices and vastly simplifies the boiler plate. Note rather than using a second environment, we simply just put everything in **base**, and with Micromamba, there isn't anything else in **base** but your environment specification. See [the `micromamba-docker` documentation](https://micromamba-docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html).

Comment: Woaah.... Ok mind blown.  I'm going to test it out this week.

Comment: Does --chown set the permissions for the owner?

Comment: @O.rka yes, and that variable stores the default user that is configured for RUN commands.

Comment: not sure if you have any insight on this but could use some help here: https://github.com/mamba-org/micromamba-docker/issues/359

Comment: @O.rka looks like the team there got you covered! I will make one comment that you really should chain the `micromamba install` and `micromamba clean` commands, otherwise you create an intermediate layer that captures the package cache and tarballs unnecessarily. Since that's on the order of hundreds of MB, it can be a consequential optimization.

Comment: I will definitely do that.  Also, I can't thank you enough for suggesting this.  I've been trying to figure out how to containerize my code and I haven't been able to get it to run as expected.  This has simplified the process a lot and FINALLY I've been able to successfully implement it after 3 or so stressful months. Again, thank you thank you thank you.