# How to create docker container with pinned versions of Python and R?

Tags: python, r, docker, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to create a docker container with specific versions of Python and R (for reasons regarding compatibility with legacy libraries that are unavailable in the latests version).

I've tried to no avail different variations of the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:2023.03-1

RUN conda config \
    --add channels defaults \
    --add channels bioconda \
    --add channels conda-forge

RUN conda install -y python=3.10.0
RUN conda install -c conda-forge -y r-base=3.6.1
```

Which after running, produces the following error:

```
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t myname/mycontainer .
[+] Building 548.0s (9/21)                                                    docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.22kB                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/continuumio/anaconda3:2023.03-1                    0.5s
 => [auth] continuumio/anaconda3:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                          0.0s
 => [ 1/16] FROM docker.io/continuumio/anaconda3:2023.03-1@sha256:6697f6ab7d940e557562c2d7c1  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 328B                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/16] RUN conda config     --add channels defaults     --add channels bioconda   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/16] RUN conda install -y python=3.10.0                                         0.0s
 => ERROR [ 4/16] RUN conda install -c conda-forge -y r-base=3.6.1                          547.4s
------                                                                                             
 > [ 4/16] RUN conda install -c conda-forge -y r-base=3.6.1:                                       
0.750 Retrieving notices: ...working... done                                                       
1.980 Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(546): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.7.1.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.7.1
35.00 done
35.00 Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
271.4 Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
532.2 Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... Segmentation fault
------
Dockerfile:9
--------------------
   7 |     
   8 |     RUN conda install -y python=3.10.0
   9 | >>> RUN conda install -c conda-forge -y r-base=3.6.1
  10 |     RUN conda install -y pandas
  11 |     RUN conda install -y biopython
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c conda install -c conda-forge -y r-base=3.6.1" did not complete successfully: exit code: 139
```

I also tried installing R with apt-get, but the results are the same.

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:2023.03-1

RUN conda config \
    --add channels defaults \
    --add channels bioconda \
    --add channels conda-forge

RUN conda install -y python=3.10.0
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg1 r-base=3.6.1 #trim-galore cutadapt
```

Which produces a similar error:

```
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t myname/mycontainer .
[+] Building 1.0s (9/22)                                                      docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.31kB                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/continuumio/anaconda3:2023.03-1                    0.3s
 => [internal] load build context                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 328B                                                             0.0s
 => [ 1/18] FROM docker.io/continuumio/anaconda3:2023.03-1@sha256:6697f6ab7d940e557562c2d7c1  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/18] RUN conda config     --add channels defaults     --add channels bioconda   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/18] RUN conda install -y python=3.10.0                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/18] RUN apt-get update                                                         0.0s
 => ERROR [ 5/18] RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg1 r-base=3.6.1 #trim-galore cutadapt       0.7s
------                                                                                             
 > [ 5/18] RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg1 r-base=3.6.1 #trim-galore cutadapt:                  
0.184 Reading package lists...                                                                     
0.550 Building dependency tree...                                                                  
0.626 Reading state information...
0.678 E: Version '3.6.1' for 'r-base' was not found
------
Dockerfile:10
--------------------
   8 |     RUN conda install -y python=3.10.0
   9 |     RUN apt-get update
  10 | >>> RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg1 r-base=3.6.1 #trim-galore cutadapt
  11 |     
  12 |     RUN conda install -c conda-forge -y r-base=3.6.1
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y curl gnupg1 r-base=3.6.1 #trim-galore cutadapt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Similar issues appear if I start the dockerfile with miniconda. Is there any reliable way to pin the versions of Python and R to in a Dockerfile?

Comment: [This looks promising](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64524896/903061)

Comment: State of the art is: 1) start from Micromamba image; 2) define the environment with YAML. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76860372/570918

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `conda` virtual environment if you want to use a specific version of Python/R.

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:2023.03-1

RUN conda config \
    --add channels defaults \
    --add channels bioconda \
    --add channels conda-forge

RUN conda create -n test_env python=3.10.0 -y

RUN conda install -n test_env -c conda-forge -y r-base=3.6.1
```

Note that you will have to install your packages inside the `test_env` environment with the `-n` flag.

Now, you can optimize this code even further if you use `mamba` over `conda` for package management. `mamba` is a drop-in replacement for `conda` and it should optimize the environment solving process. If you want to to use `miniconda`, you might as well use [`mamba`.](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba)

```
FROM condaforge/mambaforge:latest

RUN mamba config \
    --add channels defaults \
    --add channels bioconda \
    --add channels conda-forge

RUN mamba create -n test_env python=3.10.0 -y

RUN mamba install -n test_env \
    r-base=3.6.1 \
    -c conda-forge && \
    mamba clean --all -f -y && \
    echo "source activate test_env" > ~/.bashrc

ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/test_env/bin:$PATH
```

The last two lines should activate your environment as part of the Dockerfile, and your entrypoint should now be inside the environment.

If you *really* want to optimize the container build process, you want to use the least amount of RUN commands as possible. Each RUN command initiates a new shell session, and bloats the container if you have a bunch.

```
FROM condaforge/mambaforge:latest

RUN mamba config \
    --add channels defaults \
    --add channels bioconda \
    --add channels conda-forge && \
    mamba create -n test_env python=3.10.0 -y && \
    mamba install -n test_env \
    r-base=3.6.1 \
    -c conda-forge && \
    mamba clean --all -f -y && \
    echo "source activate test_env" > ~/.bashrc

ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/test_env/bin:$PATH
```